# Extracting rotation of camera from gyroscope's attitude

Tags: ios, rotation, gyroscope

I've got live feed of camera frames and corresponding readings of attitude from gyroscope on an iPhone (`CMAttitude` on iOS).

The camera and gyroscope sensors are surely located in different places on the PCB of the phone. This means the rotation of gyro isn't valid for the camera as camera and gyro aren't in the same coordinate space.

How can I get rotation relative to the camera sensor from gyroscope's measurement? Do I need to measure the physical distance between gyro and camera?

```
+---------------------------+        +---------------------------+
|             | gyro        |        |               gyro        |
|            -+-            |   ?    | |           +             |
| + cam       |             |  ===>  |-+- cam                    |
|                           |        | |                         |
|                           |        |                           |
+---------------------------+        +---------------------------+

     CMAttitude readings                 How to instead get
     are in gyroscope's                  rotation in the camera
     coordinate space                    coordinate space?
```

Comment: What do you mean rotation relative to the camera sensor? You mean the rotation of the camera sensor to some arbitrary start position (ie. world coordinates)?

Comment: Isn't this the sort of thing that the AVCam example code is there to explain?

Comment: @matt do you mean [this AVCam example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)? Unfortunately, I couldn't find any sign of use of Core Motion (and hence gyroscope) in that example.

Comment: @ACVM yes, that's what I meant (i.e. I want to get the attitude of the camera sensor instead of the attitude of the gyroscope sensor (which is AFAIK what `CMAttitude` provides)).

Comment: You're totally right, sorry about that - I meant this one: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html